# EXCEPT operator not working with foreign character set?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two VIEW that I need to compare by using the [**EXCEPT**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055.aspx) operator. The purpose is to identify if record for two table is different. The problem lies with one column (for example *fldIdentifierNo*) that may contain foreign character set, when I use EXCEPT operator it seems it cannot compare properly that *fldIdentifierNo*.

This is my query, I also tried converting the column to NVARCHAR(MAX) explicitly just to be sure and to no avail it always return that the records has a difference.

```
SELECT 
    fldIdentifierNo  -- tried it also this way CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),fldIdentifierNo)
FROM 
     this_is_the_view_local
WHERE 
    staff_no='00001'
EXCEPT
SELECT 
    fldIdentifierNo  -- tried it also this way CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),fldIdentifierNo)
FROM 
    this_is_the_other_view
WHERE 
    staff_no='00001'
```

The data I compare is like this:

[image: EXCEPT result]

This is the actual result from the editor:

[image: Actual result from editor]

**Resolved**
With the help of @T_G and @VladimirBalanov, I resolved it by finding out there is "hard-space" on one of the column. The hard-space will not be remove by using the LTRIM and RTRIM.

I used the REPLACE and changing the hard-space which is CHAR(160) (nbsp) to CHAR(32) (space).
REPLACE(column_name,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)

This is the workaround on my problem but **BETTER** I will check why there is such character on the column.

Comment: At first check whether the column values are really the same. Looking at query results in SSMS can be misleading. Try `CONVERT(varbinary(8000), N'ChD/ЧД59121278')` and compare binary result from both tables.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov: it seems they are not the same. As T_G was talking about there is a space on my column. I tried trimming the spaces but still one column is retaining the space at the end of the value. Do you possibly know why is it like that?

Comment: Is it really a space? Check the binary value, is it 0x20? LTRIM, RTRIM remove only spaces, they don't remove other non-printable characters like carriage returns or tabs.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov I solved it, there is a "hard space" on the column. I used REPLACE instead. Better check why there is a hard space on the column. Thank you!

Comment: Please consider reposting your resolution as an answer (and accepting it).

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
SELECT 
    LTRIM (RTRIM (fldIdentifierNo)) COLLATE database_default
FROM 
     this_is_the_view_local
WHERE 
    staff_no='00001'
EXCEPT
SELECT 
    LTRIM (RTRIM (fldIdentifierNo))  COLLATE database_default
FROM 
    this_is_the_other_view
WHERE 
    staff_no='00001'
```

Comment: Might there be leading or trailing spaces difference?

Comment: I trim the column and it's still the same.

Comment: Would you be able to update your wuestion and provide new information: records from view-1, then from view-2,  the expected result and result obtained not being the expected one?

Comment: That is the query I'm running and eliminated other column that is not necessary on my question. The image I sent is the actual column value I was comparing.I will post the actual result for both view.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @T_G and @VladimirBalanov, I resolved it by finding out there is "hard-space" on one of the column. The hard-space will not be remove by using the LTRIM and RTRIM.

I used the REPLACE and changing the hard-space which is CHAR(160) (nbsp) to CHAR(32) (space). REPLACE(column_name,CHAR(160),CHAR(32)

This is the workaround on my problem but BETTER I will check why there is such character on the column.